# can you insert non-sequence related comments in a fasta file?

Tags: alignment, sequence, bioinformatics, fasta

I was wondering if anyone knows how to add comments to a fasta file. I tried using the # character but it doesn't sit well with alignment algorithms/software.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

What I usually found is that there are no comments. But in the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format#History) it says that you could add comments after the `>` line if starting with `;`.  But I have never found anyone with this notation.

But I have never found any fasta file with comments. Usually the header or the name get this attribution so `> E.coli` can be converted to `> E.coli X43 methanol` as you can see [here](http://noble.gs.washington.edu/proj/crux/fasta-format.html)
But usually, as seen [here](https://www.biostars.org/p/17654/), and [here](http://emboss.sourceforge.net/docs/themes/SequenceFormats.html#id) is added as a description as said.

Comment: Yes. This is what I've noticed as well. The comments after a > character relate to a subsequent sequence. I think it just can't be done.

Comment: Well, it can be done but it will crash any program that doesn't take that into account that I think that are almost all of them. If you found this answer useful consider to mark it as so.

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to adds comment *IN* the sequence. But you could add a comment within an alternative format like one of the XML-based ones published by the NCBI.